# Upload a file from Win32 C++ program to OneDrive(SkyDrive)

Tags: c++, rest, winapi, file-upload, onedrive

I'm writing the program for uploading a file to OneDrive based on [Cordova Windows 7](https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows/blob/master/windows7/Cordova/filetransfer.c) with Visual Studio 2013(on Windows 8.1 Pro).

Although transfer of the file by POST method can do, an error "request_method_invalid:HTTP method 'POST' isn't allowed for this resource." returns.

According to the [official document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn659726.aspx#upload_a_file), it is written that can upload with POST method. If that is right, where is wrong in this code?

*[picojson](https://github.com/kazuho/picojson) is an open source JSON parser.

```
wstring filePath = L"C:\\..\\test.jpg";
wstring dest = L"https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files/test.jpg";


file = CreateFile(filePath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    SendErrorMessage(data, CONNECTION_ERR, filePath, dest);
    goto out;
}
file_size.LowPart = GetFileSize(file, &file_size.HighPart);

inet = InternetOpen(L"Cordova", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
if (!inet) {
    SendErrorMessage(data, CONNECTION_ERR, filePath, dest);
    goto out;
}

// 1- Headers
buf = new BYTE[CHUNK_SIZE];
ws = L"Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" + BOUNDARY;
if (!HttpAddRequestHeaders(req, ws.c_str(), ws.size(), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD)) {
    SendErrorMessage(data, CONNECTION_ERR, filePath, dest);
    goto end_req;
}
for (picojson::object::iterator i = headers.begin(); i != headers.end(); i++){
    if (i->second.is<wstring>() == false) continue;
    ws = i->first + L": " + i->second.get<wstring>(); // Authorization: Bearer (access_token)
    if (!HttpAddRequestHeaders(req, ws.c_str(), ws.size(), HTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD)) {
        SendErrorMessage(data, CONNECTION_ERR, filePath, dest);
        goto out;
    }
}

// 2- Contents
// 2.1 Contents headers
ws = L"";
for (picojson::object::iterator i = params.begin(); i != params.end(); i++){
    if (i->second.is<wstring>() == false) continue;
    ws += L"--" + BOUNDARY + L"\r\n";
        + L"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + i->first + L"\";\r\n\r\n"
        + i->second.get<wstring>() + L"\r\n";
}
ws += L"--" + BOUNDARY + L"\r\n"
    + L"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fileKey + L"\"; filename=\"" + fileName + L"\"\r\n"
    + L"Content-Type: " + mimeType + L"\r\n\r\n";


int utf8_len = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, ws.c_str(), -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
utf8_text = new char[utf8_len + 10];
if (!WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, ws.c_str(), ws.size(), utf8_text, utf8_len + 10, NULL, NULL)) {
    SendErrorMessage(data, CONNECTION_ERR, filePath, dest);
    goto end_req;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do the upload via POST your destination location should be the parent folder with the file name in the multipart body.  From the [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn659726.aspx#upload_a_file):

```
POST https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/files?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=A300x

--A300x
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="HelloWorld.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

Hello, World!
--A300x--
```

Comment: It works. In windows store app, since the wrong address was also successful, I did not notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That said, it's actually a lot easier to use PUT for file uploads.  In that case, the path you specified above is correct (i.e., the file name belongs in the path), and you can just write the contents of your file to the response body as is.